# Magento 1.7 Import product issue

Tags: php, magento

I import excel sheet of products in magento. porducts are appear in catalog but not appear in advance search event i set visible option to 4 means "catalog,Serach" in excel.

Comment: Have you tried doing a full reindex and then clearing the caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check, if products goes in right category and category is enabled than do a full reindex and clear the cache.