# Magento Bulk update Weight of associated products

Tags: php, magento

i had created a grouped product and added associated products to it with quantity 1 and weight 0.so when i search this grouped product in home search the product is not displayed,so is there a way to bulk update the weight of the products?i had reffered this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/266066/ and bulk updated the weight but hence the search is not working,but when i had updated the weight of each product from admin back end its working  i had almost more than 100000 products any help will be thankfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it may be issue of reindex of data, you can go through with this answer

[Magento 1.7 Import product issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577171/magento-1-7-import-product-issue/19581444#19581444)

if you still have the issue than go to admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes and click on weight to edit. On edit screen, you can set the value of 'Used in Product Listing' to 'No', if it's set to yes and reindex the data and I feel it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry the earlier post was a mistake. The issues still persists. I can see the database values are updated but I cannot see the product in search results still.

Answer (score 0):

I've written simple script to bulk update weights of the products.
I've a csv with 2 columns first column is sku and another with weights of the products to be updated.
Below is the script

```
set_time_limit(0);

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

 try{

$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$file = 'set_products_with_weight.csv';
$products = $csv->getData($file);
$count = 0;

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

foreach($products as $product)
{

    $weight = (float) $product[1];

    $query = 'UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal set value = '.$weight.' WHERE attribute_id = 80 AND entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity where sku ="'.$product[0].'")';
    $results = $writeConnection->query($query);


}

} catch(Exception $e) {

    print_r($e);

}
```

Where 80 is the attribute_id of weight attribute. You need to check this in database. OR you can update the query with inner join with attribute_id and filter by attribute_code=weight.